# Focus RT an ERP software on Ubuntu

Tags: mac

I m using a mac and I would like to know if Ubuntu would help me run Focus RT on it. Focus RT is an ERP software which runs on windows. Kindly help me with this.

Thanx 
Nik

Comment: Your best bet on getting a good answer to this specific question will be to contact the software company directly, and ask if they support Linux.  http://www.focussoftnet.com/ca/solutions-focus-RT.html

Answer (score 0):

You may have luck running Windows programs on Linux using `wine`, but a whole ERP suite is probably so complicated that there'll be issues.